# How to disable $http.pendingRequests.length for particular API calls?

Tags: angularjs, http, model-view-controller, http-headers

I have controller in angularjs where written a logic to show loader in page.

appCtrl.js

```
$rootScope.loaderExceptionCount = 0 ;
    $scope.isAnythingLoading = function() {
        console.log($http.pendingRequests, $http);
        return $http.pendingRequests.length > $rootScope.loaderExceptionCount;
    };
```

and index.html as

```
<div ng-show="isAnythingLoading()" class="pageLoader">
        <div class="loaderBackdrop"></div>
            <div class="sk-wave">
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect1"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect2"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect3"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect4"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

There is one post API call for which I don't want show loader . Can we disable loader for specific API call ?

Comment: Is it possible   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by

```
var skippedUrls = ['...'];
$scope.isAnythingLoading = function() {
  var reqCount = $http.pendingRequests
    .filter(function (req) {
      return !skippedUrls.includes(req.url);
    })
    .length;
  return  reqCount > $rootScope.loaderExceptionCount;
};
```

[The manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#pendingRequests) states `$http.pendingRequests` purpose clearly:

> Array of config objects for currently pending requests. This is
>   primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes.

More solid solution would involve `$http` interceptor that does the same thing as above, a separate service that holds loading state and a directive that binds the state to UI element.